# Sending 2 request at same time in Struts 1.4 and jBoss 4.2

Tags: jboss, request, struts

I don't know why but all the requests in my application are being duplicated, it's making a POST request and them a GET request of the same action, I didn't change any configuration, and even the oldest action are behaving this way, and I didn't change those as well. Anyone knows what is going on? Everything was normal until yesterday.

Comment: Not enough information to help.

Comment: Requests sent by whom? To whom? You changed nothing at all (the server it was deployed)?

Comment: I know what's going on even if you don't know it I will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Struts 1.4 does not seem to exist so I guess there's at least a mistake in your question.
(cf http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi, http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-core and http://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html)